# Zend Framework - PDO Insert not working due to empty primary key

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo

I have joined another developer in working on a project using Zend Framework and I can't get any database insert statements to work on my local machine. For testing purposes I am using root user and I can get all other statements to work.

My configuration is nginx 1.6.2, PHP Version 5.5.18, and PDO Mysql API Version 5.6.21.

The server configuration is apache 2.0, PHP Version 5.4.22 and PDO Mysql API Version 5.5.34

The problem is every time I try to insert a row into the database I get an error like this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id_client' at row 1'
```

In this instance I am trying to insert a row into the `$table` `client` using the following code, which is pretty standard in Zend:

```
$this->_db->insert ( $table, $values );
$id = $this->_db->lastInsertId ();
```

This is the array `$values` I am trying to insert

```
array (size=13)
  'id_client' => string '' (length=0)
  'id_profile' => string '2' (length=1)
  'status' => string '1' (length=1)
  'client' => string 'ABC' (length=3)
  'contact' => string 'Fred' (length=4)
  'phone' => string '0412345678' (length=10)
  'address' => string 'Sydney Rd' (length=6)
  'suburb' => string 'Sydney' (length=6)
  'state' => string 'New South Wales' (length=15)
  'post_code' => string '2000' (length=4)
  'notas' => string '' (length=0)
  'bg' => string '#FEAF1D' (length=7)
  'logo' => string '' (length=0)
```

This is the database structure for the table `client` which shows the primary key `id_client` at the end

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client` (
  `id_client` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `client` char(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact` char(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` char(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` char(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `suburb` char(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` char(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_code` char(6) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `county` char(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `notas` text COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci,
  `logo` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `bg` char(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_profile` int(2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

ALTER TABLE `client`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_client`), ADD KEY `id_profile` (`id_profile`);
```

As you can see in the `$values` array there is no value for `id_client` which is why I am getting the error, but in the zend framework (and others) the insert statement should still work as the database will automatically assign a value based upon the `AUTO_INCREMENT`. That's how it is working on the server, but it's not doing so on my localhost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: remove the id_client from the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the column client_id from the list of values that you are trying to insert, as including it will make the database attempt to insert the value you provided (and blank is a value).

Second, you need to change the column definition from `` id_client` int(20) NOT NULL,` to ``id_client`int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,` so that the database knows how to determine the correct value for that column on insert.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your id_client is AUTO_INCREMENT, your table definition seems not to have an auto increment field defined.

Secondly as @dixromos98 mentioned remove id_client from the array as well.